# Docker PermissionError: [Errno 1] Unable to load configuration file (Operation not permitted): '/app/application.cfg' (windows)

Tags: python, windows, docker

I'm completely new to docker.

this is my dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM ubuntu:22.04

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils \
   && echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections

RUN apt-get install -y locales \
   && localedef -i en_US -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias en_US.UTF-8 \
   && localedef -i it_IT -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias it_IT.UTF-8
ENV LANG it_IT.utf8

RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip

COPY ./src .

RUN chown 1000:1000 -R /app # Added after some research

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--port=5000"]
```

I build it using:

```
docker build --tag python-template .
```

and it seems to work fine, but when I go to the next step:

```
 docker run -d -v 'C:\Users\Sparapan.F.GRUPPOFIN\Desktop\pyscripts\API\application-docker.cfg:/app/application.cfg' --name app python-template
```

it works fine on the console (it output a long alphanumeric string), but it the docker desktop the container "app" is grey and in the details it shows the error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Unable to load configuration file (Operation not permitted): '/app/application.cfg'
```

The file application-docker.cfg contains 4 parameters that I'm using in my application, and I've manually created it.

Also tried to launch it using:

```
docker run -d -v 'C:\Users\Sparapan.F.GRUPPOFIN\Desktop\pyscripts\API\application-docker.cfg:/app/application.cfg' --name app -u 1000:1000 python-template
```

but same thing.

After reading some similar questions here, I've added the command:

```
RUN chown 1000:1000 -R /app
```

but nothing changes.

Thanks!